# Programming error in allocating new stack

Tags: c++, stack

I am writing a program to implement a stack which works like a real world stack means it topples when the size of a stack reaches threshold and therefore need to create a new stack for inserting that new element.

Below is my program for this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<stack>

using namespace std;

class stack_of_plates
{
   vector<stack<int> > stacks;
   unsigned int stack_size;
   public:
   stack_of_plates(unsigned int size=100)
   {
       stack_size=size;
   }

   void push(int data)
   {
       if(stacks.empty())
       {
           stack<int> *sptr= new stack<int>; //on debugging Segmentation fault at thisline
           stacks.push_back(*sptr);
       }

       vector<stack<int> >::iterator it=stacks.end();
       if(it->size()==stack_size)
       {
           stack<int> *sptr= new stack<int>; //on debugging Segmentation fault at thisline
           stacks.push_back(*sptr);
       }
       it->push(data);
   }

   void pop()
   {
       if(stacks.empty())
       {
           cout<<"\nEmpty Stack";
           return ;
       }
       vector<stack<int> >::iterator it=stacks.end();
       if(it->empty())
       {
           it--;
       }
       it->pop();
   }
   int top()
   {
       if(stacks.empty())
       {
           cout<<"\nEmpty Stack";
           return 0;
       }
       vector<stack<int> >::iterator it=stacks.end();
       if(it->empty())
       {
           it--;
       }
       return it->top();
   }
};


int main()
{
   stack_of_plates ss;
   ss.push(1);
   ss.push(2);
   cout<<ss.top();
   return 0;
}
```

On compiling it gives no error or warning. However program terminates with unusual error. 
On debugging its giving segmentation fault error indicating problem in allocating new stack. 
Kindly help me how should i change my code while allocating the new stack. Please help me removing this error.

Comment: What is the "programming error" exactly?

Comment: Noo, *that's* not what they mean by "stack pointer"...

Comment: This is complete bogus: `stack<int> *sptr= new stack<int>; stacks.push_back(*sptr);`. It should be either `stacks.push_back(stack<int>());`, or `stacks.emplace_back();`, or `stacks.resize(stacks.size() + 1);`

Comment: My question: I know i am making mistaking in allocating a new stack. thats why precisely I posted here for help. Kindly help me what should I write there in the lines where I have commented.

Comment: @Kerrek: stacks.push_back(stack<int>()); is not working either...

Comment: Two points: If you allocate the stack on the heap and then push them like you do, you will have a memory leak, as you push a _copy_ onto the stack. Second is that `generic_container.end()` doesn't return the last entry in `generic_container`, so you have to use `it--` before using the iterator.

Comment: @amit and Mimi...no error is shown by the complier, on run time it terminates saying "stack_of_plates.exe has encountered a problem and needs to close.  We are sorry for the inconvenience."

Comment: @Joachim: Our requirement I need to create a new stack and push it on the back of the vector "stacks". How can we do that. Appreciate if you can help with code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`stacks.end();` refers to the (nonexistent) element after the end of the vector. You can't dereference it; doing so will cause undefined behaviour, possibly a segmentation fault.

It's not quite clear what you're doing there, but if you want an iterator for the last element, then either decrement it:

```
vector<stack<int> >::iterator it=stacks.end();  // points past the end
--it;                                           // points to last element
```

or use a reverse iterator (in which case, you use `++` rather than `--` to move backwards through the sequence):

```
vector<stack<int> >::reverse_iterator it=stacks.rbegin();
```

Adding an element to a vector can invalidate it, so the `it->push_back(data)` at the end of `push()` is incorrect. You could avoid using an iterator here:

```
void push() {
    if (stacks.empty() || stacks.back().size()==stack_size) {
        // See below for explanation of this change
        stacks.push_back(stack<int>());
    }
    stacks.back().push(data);
}
```

In `pop()`, you probably want to remove the last stack if it's empty; otherwise, you'll end up with two empty stacks at the end, and your code will erroneously try to `pop` from one of those. Again, doing that could cause a segmentation fault or other undefined behavoiur. You probably want something like:

```
void pop() {
    if (stacks.empty()) {
        cout<<"\nEmpty Stack";
        return ;
    }
    stacks.back().pop();
    if (stacks.back().empty()) {
        stacks.pop_back();
    }
}
```

And now we've established an invariant that the last stack is never empty, `top` can be a bit simpler:

```
int top() {
    if (stacks.empty()) {
        cout<<"\nEmpty Stack";
        return 0;
    }
    return stacks.back().top();
}
```

Also, you usually don't want to create objects using `new`, especially in a case like this where you're putting a copy of the object into the vector and then discarding the pointer, leaking the allocated memory. You can add an empty stack to the vector like this:

```
stacks.push_back(stack<int>());
```

Sometimes (but not in this case) you might want to store pointers to allocated objects in a container; in that case, either remember to delete them when they're removed from the container, or store smart pointers such as `std::unique_ptr`. But in this case, just store objects.

Answer (score 1):

There are many problems with the code, so it is hard to say which one is the direct cause of your problem. You need the clean them up one by one and then retest. If you still have a problem, post your new code here.

Here is the list:

1. You have a memory leak from your allocation with new. Since you have a vector of stacks, all you need to do is resize the vector and a new stack will be allocated. So

   `stacks.resize(stacks.size() + 1)`;

   instead of

   `stack<int> *sptr= new stack<int>`;
   `stacks.push_back(*sptr)`;
2. vector<>.end() returns an iterator that point to an element AFTER the last one, which is why @Joachim suggested that you need to decrement the iterator before you use it.
3. You have a logical error when you check whether to transfer storage to a new stack - after checking is the size of the last stack is the max, and creating a new one, you keep pushing on the old one.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much guys. I have realized my mistakes. The only problem was i was using .end() and not decrementing iterator. I have rectified it and its working fine now. 
I am just wondering about the comment of Mike why its not recommended to use iterator to push data in the element of vector.

Answer (score 0):

`std::stack<int>` already has the functionality you show in your example, so there is no need for a `std::vector< std::stack<int> >`.  By just pushing and popping to the `std::stack<int>` you avoid most of the issues your having in your code.  There is no reason to limit `std::stack<int>` to `stack_size`.

Next to that, when you need the last entry in a container, use `back()` instead of `end()`.